# Toronto Airport (YYZ) to Sanur Bali Indonesia

Tags: air-travel, canada, bali, timezones

I currently reside in Toronto, Canada and I'm thinking of travelling to Sanur, Bali (Indonesia). If I need to be there on a Saturday at noon Bali time. What flight time should I pick in order to arrive in Sanur before noon? I just don't understand if I would be there same day or the day after from Toronto.

Comment: This is not a travel agency. Why are you enable to find a flight using the normal booking services?

Comment: The time zone in Bali is 12 hours ahead of Toronto, and the time for a cross-Pacific flight is at least 12 hours (usually more).  The difference between local Toronto time at departure and local Bali time at arrival is therefore at least 24 hours, or a full day.

Answer (score 6):

I first Googled [sanur airport](https://www.google.ca/search?complete=0&&gws_rd=ssl&q=sanur+airport) and without clicking anything I can see it says "Sanur is a 20 minute taxi ride from the Ngurah Rai International Airport" and several "Transfers from Bali Denpasar International airport to Sanur". OK so our airport is Denpasar. Next I entered Toronto and Denpasar into Kayak and restricted landing times to Saturday. [image] It prints in big red letters that it lands on Saturday. So then it would seem that unless you want to leave really, really early from Toronto, Friday won't do. Leaving on Thursday:

[image]

As a rule of thumb, on this route apparently it takes a day to fly (plus/minus a few hours depending on route and layover) and half a day timezone difference (this is actually 12 hours) -- from Toronto to Denpasar, both ahead. So leaving Toronto Thursday early afternoon lands you in Denpasar at a time which is Friday early afternoon in Toronto and accordingly just after midnight in Denpasar so you can take a good night sleep before doing whatever you needed to do in Sanur Saturday afternoon. I personally would certainly prefer such an itin because it takes care of adjusting to the Denpasar TZ: you will be dead tired by the time you land, and it is, indeed, night. As a general rule of thumb unless I have friends/family picking me up at an airport hotel, I would sleep at the airport and figure out my way to the destination the next day. After spending 20hrs in a dry overpressurized aluminium tube I just want a bed.

Finally, according to ITA Matrix which is able to search for routes regardless whether seats are available, this 22:25 flight is actually the fastest if you are leaving on a Thursday. It says something about the distance that going the other way around via Amsterdam and Singapore only takes 24:50.

Comment: You would stay at Ngurah Rai the first night rather than hop a cab 20 minutes to Samur?

Comment: It's past midnight. Depends of course on the accommodation in Samur but in general -- yes.

Comment: Personally I would rather head to taxi que and catch a ride to my destination, rather than wait at the airport for airport hotel shuttle. Then wake up at the beach not at the airport.

Comment: Great answer! It shows a process and solution worked for the requested example. That is very useful!